# Long-term future of own zero-vote questions

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions, zero-voted-posts

I know that there exists a policy of clean-up on SO that will probably make that questions with a negative or zero vote, or questions without answers, or duplicate questions, etc., will be deleted on long-term.

But sometimes, even if the question has zero votes and/or if it is a duplicate, it could be useful in maybe 5 years, at least for myself, **as future reference**.

Example:

- [zero-voted question, 1 accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357215/add-ticks-for-days-on-pandas-plot)
- [zero-voted question, zero-voted self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205569/dont-log-certain-requests-in-apache-access-log)

**Is there a way, for users, to not lose any of their content in the next 20 years, even if the question is zero voted (or has negative votes)?**

Answer (score 11):

In both examples, the questions have an (accepted) answer. This will prevent them from being auto-deleted by [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), even if they would be closed in the future. Of course, this is pending any policy changes. Also, closed questions can be [deleted manually](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), but there need to be good reasons for that. See [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) on Übermeta for more information about how a post can be deleted.

And even if your question would be deleted, if you have the link *bookmarked* (outside Stack Overflow), you will still be able to view it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for clarifying the [Roomba deletion criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Is there a way to be able to see the questions/answers forever, even if deleted, even if < 10k user? Will it still be listed in my user-question-list ?

Comment: `even if your question would be deleted, if you have the link, you will still be able to view it.` For how long, and will the link always appear in my user page?

Comment: @Basj no, it doesn't appear in your user page.

Comment: so if any of my questions is deleted and if I have no bookmark of them I have no way to find it again? something else: are you sure a 3-years-ago-deleted question can be viewed by a < 10k user ?

Comment: @Basj yes, that's right. And you will always be able to see your own deleted questions.